# SQl apply where clause to only one field

Tags: sql, teradata

I'd like to apply a WHERE clause to just one field of my select query. The internet told me to use CASE WHEN in the line where I'm selecting my fields and to then remove the where clause. But I was then told that my "`selected non aggregate values must be part of the associated group."`

The original query looked like this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AS Date1, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT EMAIL) END AS Subs, 
    SUM(DWELL_MINUTES) AS Dwell
FROM VwNIMEventFct
INNER JOIN VwNIMUserDim ON VwNIMUserDim.NIM_USER_ID = VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID
INNER JOIN TmpNIMSalesForceDB ON VwNIMUserDim.USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS = EMAIL


WHERE Date1 >= '2013-11-01'
// The problem is here, in the AND clause
AND (SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE > VwNIMEventFct.EVENT_TIMESTAMP OR SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE 
IS NULL)

GROUP BY Date1
ORDER BY Date1
```

I then changed the query after doing some searching to this:

```
  SELECT 
    CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AS Date1, 
    CASE WHEN (SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE > Date1 OR SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE IS NULL)
        THEN COUNT(DISTINCT TmpNIMSalesForceDB.EMAIL) END AS Subs, 
    SUM(VwNIMEventFct.DWELL_MINUTES) AS Dwell
    FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
   INNER JOIN VwNIMUserDim ON VwNIMUserDim.NIM_USER_ID = VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID
   INNER JOIN TmpNIMSalesForceDB ON VwNIMUserDim.USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS = EMAIL
   WHERE Date1 >= '2013-11-01'
   GROUP BY Date1
   ORDER BY Date1
```

I'd like to select:
 1) the date as per "Date1" in the query, then, 
 2) for each date, the count of distinct email addresses where the SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE is either NULL or in the future (greater than Date1), 
 3) Sum of a field (I'm fine here)

How do I do number 2?

EDIT based on answer:
Does this part of the select query ignore and thus not count blank records when 
SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE is null?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE  WHEN TmpNIMSalesForceDB.SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE > Date1 OR TmpNIMSalesForceDB.SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE IS NULL
             THEN TmpNIMSalesForceDB.EMAIL END) AS Subs,
```

I need to count all records where SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE is blank/null or where those dates are after Date1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your CASE statement inside the COUNT, rather than vice versa, as it needs to be evaluated for each row (which case should this row fall in) and then aggregated across each  group (how many rows in that group fell in the non-null group).

```
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE > Date1 OR SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE IS NULL)
    THEN TmpNIMSalesForceDB.EMAIL END) AS Subs
```

The COUNT will ignore the NULLs implicitly left by the lack of an ELSE clause in the CASE statement, thus counting only the distinct EMAIL values from rows which met the condition.

Comment: "The COUNT will ignore the NULLs implicitly left by the lack of an ELSE clause in the CASE statement" that changes things. I changed the query and it ran so that's good but the results were not what I expected to see. I need to include when the date is null not ignore - count the emails when the SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE is blank.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. Think of CASE as like a function, which returns some value for use in the output or passed to some other function; if the row matches a specified condition,  the result of the CASE is the specified value; if it matches no condition, the value of the ELSE clause is used; if there is no ELSE, the result is NULL. This has nothing to do with whether the input being examined contains NULLs.

Comment: Ah, yes I was misunderstanding. So the condition is met - do the thing (count). Looks like I have another problem as the numbers are not what's expected. Thanks for your help on this part though

Comment: Looking at your question, the original query compared against VwNIMEventFct.EVENT_TIMESTAMP, but the modified one against Date1. Could this explain your current discrepancy?

Comment: Date1 is derived from VwNIMEventFct.EVENT_TIMESTAMP though. I had thought that could be it. Still investigating

Answer (score 1):

Put the `case` statement inside of the `count` function.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AS Date1, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE 
             WHEN SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE > Date1 OR SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE IS NULL
             THEN TmpNIMSalesForceDB.EMAIL END)) AS Subs, 
    SUM(VwNIMEventFct.DWELL_MINUTES) AS Dwell
FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
    INNER JOIN VwNIMUserDim 
        ON VwNIMUserDim.NIM_USER_ID = VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID
    INNER JOIN TmpNIMSalesForceDB 
        ON VwNIMUserDim.USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS = EMAIL
WHERE Date1 >= '2013-11-01'
GROUP BY Date1
ORDER BY Date1
```

Comment: It's kinda hard to tell as there is no sample data, but I think you are going to have to add EMAIL to the Group By clause rather than use DISTINCT. Then you can have "sum( case ... 1 else 0 end ) as Subs"